# Parsing XML with namespaces using jQuery $().find

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, namespaces

I'm trying to get the contents of a XML document element, but the element has a colon in it's name.

This line works for every element but the ones with a colon in the name:

```
$(this).find("geo:lat").text();
```

I assume that the colon needs escaping. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Use a backslash, which itself should be escaped so JavaScript doesn't eat it:

```
$(this).find("geo\\:lat").text();
```

Comment: @Vaske, I was seeing the same thing in Chrome using one of the latest versions of jQuery. Using the second half of node name after the colon worked for me. Used `.find("lat")` instead of `.find("geo\\:lat")` and it worked for me.

Comment: @Mike yes that helps but I had namespace problem, general problem with my returning XML that it contains <title> and <mine:title> and chrome in that case pull it together :(

Comment: It isn't working for me in FF but I found this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/853740/jquery-xml-parsing-with-namespaces

Comment: `.find` just like `getElementsByTagName` doesn't behave the same across browsers (in particular Chrome and Firefox). If you're interesting in the direct children, use `.children`, which does work across browsers. More on: http://wiki.orbeon.com/forms/doc/contributor-guide/browser#TOC-Get-elements-with-prefixes

Comment: I referenced @MikeGrace's comment in the answer to the related question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30040350/775359

Answer (score 11):

That isn't just an ordinary element name.  That's a qualified name, meaning that it is a name that specifically refers to an element type within a namespace.  The element type name is 'lat', and the namespace prefix is 'geo'.

Right now, jQuery can't deal with namespaces very well, see [bug 155](http://dev.jquery.com/ticket/155) for details.

Right now, as a workaround, you should be able to select these elements with just the local name:

```
$(this).find("lat").text();
```

If you have to distinguish between element types with the same local name, then you can use `filter()`:

```
var NS = "http://example.com/whatever-the-namespace-is-for-geo";
$(this).find("lat").filter(function() { return this.namespaceURI == NS; }).text();
```

**Edit:** my mistake, I was under the impression that patch had already landed.  Use Adam's suggestion for the selector, and `filter()` if you need the namespacing too:

```
var NS = "http://example.com/whatever-the-namespace-is-for-geo";
$(this).find("geo\\:lat").filter(function() { return this.namespaceURI == NS; }).text();
```

Answer (score 4):

if you have a **jquery selector problem with chrome or webkit** not selecting it try

```
$(this).find('[nodeName=geo:lat]').text();
```

this way it works in all browsers

Comment: It's worth noting that as of jQuery 1.7 there were issues with some of the work-arounds for finding namespaced elements.  See these links for more information:


http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/10377
http://www.steveworkman.com/html5-2/javascript/2011/improving-javascript-xml-node-finding-performance-by-2000/

Comment: Definitely recommend checking out the 2nd link ArnisAndy provided in his comment above. It beats all of the other solutions.

Comment: The link to steveworkman really helped. This works in Chrome and FF for me:
`$(xData.responseXML).find("z\\:row, row").each(function() {

// Do stuff

});`