# Parse XML using JQuery in Safari

Tags: jquery, xml, parsing, namespaces

I've got the following below XML and would like to parse this with JQuery in Safari web browser. I just want to print out the userName and need some assistance with how the function would be written.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<ns3:Account xmlns:ns2="http://oec.api.opsource.net/schemas/organization" .. >
<ns3:userName>rdyer</ns3:userName>
<ns3:fullName>Joe Public</ns3:fullName>
<ns3:firstName>Joe</ns3:firstName>
<ns3:lastName>Public</ns3:lastName>
<ns3:emailAddress>jpublic24583@pop.net</ns3:emailAddress>
<ns3:orgId>1831c1a9-9c03-44df-a5a4-f2a4662d6bde</ns3:orgId>
<ns3:roles>
<ns3:role>
<ns3:name>primary administrator</ns3:name>
</ns3:role>
</ns3:roles>
</ns3:Account>
```

Comment: Similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/853740/jquery-xml-parsing-with-namespaces

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently `$('ns3\\:userName',xml)` breaks down in jQuery 1.3.2 under webkit, but never fear, Sizzle has the power still, just filter on the attribute 'nodeName' try `$('[nodeName=ns3:userName]',xml)`

Example:

```
<div id='username'></div>
<script>
$(function() {
  // When the DOM is ready - perform AJAX to get the XML:
  $.get('/myxml.xml', {}, function(xml) {
    var $username = $("[nodeName=ns3:userName]", xml);
    // put the text from our node into the text of the empty div:
    $("#username").text($username.text());
  }, "xml");
});
</script>
```

Comment: What if I didn't use jQuery?  Any other options?

Comment: That method works with jQuery just fine (sizzle is a part of it) sorry if that was confusing...  I'm unsure about non-jQuery ways of parsing it.