# Parsing XML containing namespaces with jQuery (or JavaScript)

Tags: jquery, xml

I've been working on a big jQuery project for a while and everything was going smoothly until I tried parsing XML with namespaces.  I'm using jQuery 1.4.2 and I've tried a few different [solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/853740/jquery-xml-parsing-with-namespaces):

```
$(xml).find('[nodeName=ns:blah]')...
$(xml).find('ns\\:blah')...
```

And I tried the [jQuery.xmlns.js plugin](http://www.rfk.id.au/static/scratch/jquery.xmlns.js) but it doesn't seem to be working either.

The XML is formatted similar to:

```
<response xmlns:ns='http://example.com/ex/'>
  <response>SUCCESS</response>
  <action>QUERY</action>
  <data>
    <ns:blah>Trying to reach me!</ns:blah>
  </data>
</response>
```

Does anyone know of a solution, preferably using jQuery or a cross-browser Javascript implementation?

EDIT: Whoops, I was escaping the correctly in the code, just not in here.  I've corrected it.

Answer (score 1):

Your escaping should look like this (backslashes):

```
$(xml).find('ns\\:blah')...
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/cUhZH/

<s>Upgrade to the latest version of jQuery. I believe there some fixes in `1.4.3` with regard to selecting namespaced attributes.</s>

Comment: It works in your example, but not in my code.  I tried copying and pasting my code into jsFiddle and it works fine.

Comment: Weird, it works if I build a test page and include jquery 1.4.2 but when I'm using the bundled jquery + plugins lib that the other developers are using then it doesn't work.  I suppose I need to figure out whether they're really using 1.4.2 like it says.

Comment: @ravun - You want to be sure to have only *one* version of jQuery loaded. To test which version you're running, try `alert(jQuery.fn.jquery);` and see what it tells you.

Comment: It shows 1.4.2. For some reason if I replace the jquery core code with 1.4.4 it works fine.  I could see if the others are willing to upgrade.  However, another issue is that 'ns\\:blah' doesn't work on all browsers (it didn't work in IE7) and '[nodeName=ns:blah]' doesn't work either.

Comment: @ravun - Yes, as I originally indicated in my answer, there were some fixes after `1.4.2` with regard to the `:` character in selectors. (I crossed it out because I couldn't reproduce the issue.) With regard to IE7, did it work for you with `1.4.4`? If not, I think there need to be extra considerations made for IE with regard to XML. jQuery doesn't really parse the XML. I believe it just attempts to use the browser's `innerHTML`, and therefore treats it as DOM nodes. I think IE has issues with this because of the custom tag names.

Comment: @patrick dw - Thanks.  I don't really remember, but I believe it did NOT work in IE with 1.4.4.  I ended up using Sarissa.js and it works great.