# Injecting a tag having an attribute with colon in it using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, xhtml

I'm trying to inject below span in a div using jquery.

```
HTML:
<span epub:type="pagebreak" id="pagePrefix" title="1"></span>

JS:
$('div').html('<span epub:type="pagebreak" id="pagePrefix" title="1"></span>');
```

and getting the following error, `SyntaxError: DOM Exception 12`

any workaround this?

Comment: change epub:type to epub-type.. or to be strict with html use data-epub-type

Answer (score 5, accepted):

jQuery uses `innerHTML` when you pass serialized DOM nodes to `$('div').html()`. This works fine as long as your `DOCTYPE` is any flavor of `html`. However, with the `DOCTYPE` of `xhtml` your serialized DOM nodes must clear [some additional cases](http://www.w3.org/TR/2008/WD-html5-20080610/dom.html#innerhtml1) before being inserted into the document. According to [W3.org](http://www.w3.org/TR/2008/WD-html5-20080610/dom.html#innerhtml1), a serialized DOM node containing an `Attr` node, `Text` node, `CDATASection` node, `Comment` node, or `ProcessingInstruction` node whose data contains characters that are not matched by the XML Char production (including U+003A COLON ":") must raise an `INVALID_STATE_ERR` exception.

The [W3](http://www.w3.org/TR/2008/WD-html5-20080610/dom.html#innerhtml1) also specifies the algorithm that user agents must run when setting the `innerHTML` DOM attribute on `HTMLElements` and `HTMLDocuments` in an XML(XHTML) context. Step 2 in that algorithm is:

> If the `innerHTML` attribute is being set on an element, the user agent must feed the parser just created the string corresponding to the start tag of that element, declaring all the namespace prefixes that are in scope on that element in the DOM, as well as declaring the default namespace (if any) that is in scope on that element in the DOM.

The user agent doesn't know that you've specified the `epub` namespace on a parent element because the current context is outside the root context. Therefore you need to specify the namespace for the serialized DOM nodes when you append to the DOM.

```
$('div').html('<span xmlns:epub="http://www.idpf.org/2007/ops" 
        epub:type="pagebreak" id="pagePrefix" title="1"></span>');
```

[jsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/brianhadaway/g6xF7/).

Answer (score 3):

Escape the colon:

```
$('div').html('<span epub\:type="pagebreak" id="pagePrefix" title="1"></span>');
```

Comment: its not working because the page i'm running the jquery code is xhtml.. any other way?

Comment: How is it failing? What are you getting out instead? Escaping the character should only be of interest to JavaScript.

Comment: I tried renaming the page from .xhtml to .html and remove `<!--?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?-->` and your code starts working. But i can not rename the page to html. so what to do?

Comment: Perhaps [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4825920/901048) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/853740/901048) will help? I searched for "xml jquery attribute colon" and got a few more results.

Comment: nothing helped. I think we can not inject dom having colon in them using jquery html() for xhtml page.

Comment: I wish I could give you two votes for this tip! escaping the colon solved my problem of trying to remove attributes with colon such as xmlns:xlink

Answer (score 1):

```
$('div').append('<span />').attr('epub\:type', 'pagebreak').attr('id', 'pagePrefix').attr('title', '1');
```

Comment: i can not separate all attributes as I'm getting a huge html data from a service.