# Understanding this namespace workaround for parsing XML with JQuery

Tags: jquery, xml, picasa

I've been struggling with how to pull the text from inside a tag that contains a colon in an XML file (my original question is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4916882/simple-xml-parsing-with-google-picasa-api-and-jquery)). In my specific case, I'm working with the Google Picasa API and trying to grab the "gphoto:id" tag. This was wasn't working:

```
var albumId = $(this).children('gphoto:id').text();
```

I found the answer to my problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/853740/jquery-xml-parsing-with-namespaces/1901903#1901903), but I'm unfamiliar with the JQuery syntax used to fix the problem:

```
$('[nodeName=rs:data],data')
```

or, in the context of my question:

```
var albumId = $(this).find('[nodeName=gphoto:id]').text();
```

Can someone provide some insight into this workaround?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. This uses the [Attribute Equals Selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/).