# Consuming Java JAX-RS from jquery problem

Tags: java, jquery, jax-rs

I'm trying to consume a JAX-RS Webservice written in Java from Jquery.
I succeeded when my jquery version was set to 1.4.3. But I need for another purpose to updgrade my jquery version (to 1.5.1). Since then, my call to the webservice fails.

Does anyone has ever encountered such problem ??

Thanks for your answers

Comment: Can you give any more info, like what error, and/or an example of the XML?

Comment: I've got from the error callback = textStatus : error, errorThrown : Transport Error*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some [known issues, and workarounds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/853740/jquery-xml-parsing-with-namespaces) if the actual problem is with parsing a namespace. Apparently the issue came up somewhere between 1.4.4 and 1.5.0.

HTH

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug in Jquery in version 1.5.x for Opera and IE browser which don't support CORS...
No solution has been found yet