# jQuery's parseXML fails (invalid XML) when using namespaces

Tags: jquery, xml, xml-parsing, jquery-xml

If I try the following:

```
var xmlObject = $($.parseXML('<foo xs:type="one type">bar</foo>'));
```

jQuery returns a parsing error:

```
Invalid XML: <foo xs:type="onetype">bar</foo> - { "stack": ".error@http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js:3 .parseXML@http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js:3
```

But if I try:

```
var xmlObject = $($.parseXML('<foo xs-type="one type">bar</foo>'));
```

it works fine. In my current development, I will call a server and get the xml result as a string. And this string will contain namespaces like `xs:type`. Then I'll have to parse the xml and do some other stuff with the results. Do I have to remove all the colons from the string before parsing it with parseXML? Is there any workaround for this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Parsing xml namespace with jQuery. Help needed!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5463417/parsing-xml-namespace-with-jquery-help-needed)

Comment: @adeneo, the accepted answer in that link suggests to use the DOMParser, and I would like to use jQuery (it's way cleaner). Is there any way to do it using jQuery?

Comment: have you tried to complement your `foo` element with a namespace declaration ( ie. `<foo xmlns:xs="http://ns.example.com" xs:type="one type">`) ?

Comment: thanks @collapsar, that seems to work!! Unfortunately the response I get from my server does not include the namespace declaration, which means I will have to do it myself.