# How to parse xml attributes with jQuery alone?

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml

I'm already parsing xml successfully but i'm stuck at getting an attribute of childrens.

XML Example:

```
<entries>
    <entry>
        <media:thumbnail url="blah" />
    </entry>
</entries>
```

Javascript/ jQuery:

```
$.get('data.xml', function(d){
    $(d).find('entry').each(function(){
        var $entry = $(this);
        var pic = $entry.find('media:thumbnail').attr('url');
    })
});
```

That javascript doesn't work for me to get an attribute.
What's the problem?

Comment: your js is correct. the problem has to be something else.

Comment: If you use `console.log(d);` what do you see?

Comment: Works just fine for me. Is your response content-type correct?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Aah, namespaces are a different kind of animal, it wasn't in your original post. You have to escape the `:` in your selector.

```
var pic = $entry.find('media\\:thumbnail').attr('url');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/JSrJe/1/

See also [jQuery XML parsing with namespaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/853740/jquery-xml-parsing-with-namespaces)

Comment: Now that's what im talking about, Thanks a ton!!

Answer (score 1):

try this out

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: 'data.xml,
    dataType: "xml",
    success: function(xml) {
        $(xml).find('entry').each(function(){
            var $entry = $(this);
            var pic = $entry.find('picture').attr('url');
            alert(pic);
        })
    },
    error: function(xhr, status, error) {
        if (xhr.status != 404) {alert(error);} else {alert("404 xml not found");}
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  $.get('data.xml', function(d) {
    $(d).find('entry').each(function() {
        var $entry = $(this);
        var pic = $e`enter code here`ntry.find('media\\:thumbnail, thumbnail').attr('url');
    })
});
```