# xml parsing using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a XML like

```
<root>
<Branch CO_CODE="9" CO_CITY_ST="AHMEDABAD"/>
<Branch CO_CODE="6" CO_CITY_ST="BANGALORE"/>
<Branch CO_CODE="4" CO_CITY_ST="DELHI"/>
<Branch CO_CODE="3" CO_CITY_ST="HYDERABAD"/>
<Branch CO_CODE="5" CO_CITY_ST="JAIPUR"/>
<Branch CO_CODE="1" CO_CITY_ST="KOLKATA"/>
<Branch CO_CODE="8" CO_CITY_ST="LUCKNOW"/>
<Branch CO_CODE="10" CO_CITY_ST="MUMBAI"/>
<Branch CO_CODE="2" CO_CITY_ST="SURAT"/>
<Branch CO_CODE="7" CO_CITY_ST="VARANASI"/>
</root>
```

I am try to parsing it using javascript I have done still now

```
$(xml).find("Branch").each(function()  
{
    var str = $(this).text() +' ';
    alert(str);
});
```

It is giving 10 alert but how can I show **CO_CODE** and **CO_CITY_ST** value?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to parse xml attributes with jQuery alone?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5747335/how-to-parse-xml-attributes-with-jquery-alone)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**`CO_CODE`** and **`CO_CITY_ST`** are attributes of `Branch` tag.  So you can get it using **`.attr`**

```
$(xml).find("Branch").each(function()  
{
    var str = $(this).text() +' ';
    var code = $(this).attr('CO_CODE'); //returns Co_CODE
    var city = $(this).attr('CO_CITY_ST'); //returns CO_CITY_ST
    alert(str);
});
```