# parse restful webservice xml response with javascript

Tags: jquery, parsing, xpath, namespaces

I want to parse the following xml which is the response from an restful webservice:

```
<ns2:list xmlns="urn:foo1:foo" xmlns:ns2="foo2:foo">

   <entityData>
      <namedAttributes>...</namedAttributes>
      <dynamicEnums>...</dynamicEnums>
   </entityData>

   <ns2:employees>
      <ns2:user id="test">
          <ns2:name genderTitle="0" firstName="Rock" surName="Solid"></ns2:name>
      </ns2:user >
   </ns2:employees>
</ns2:list>
```

If I try a xpath-expression I only get [object Object] as alert:

```
function parse(xml){
   var test= $(this).find('/ns2:list/ns2:employees/ns2:user[85]/ns2:name');
   alert(test);
};
```

Adding .text()-method like: 
  var test= $(this).find('/ns2:list/ns2:employees/ns2:user[85]/ns2:name').text(); only makes the alert empty...

The xpath expression should not be wrong, I used Firebug to get the expression, maybe in this example some typing error.

Anyone knows whats wrong?
Or the other way round: how to alert fields like firstName?

Comment: I have a very simple namespace. How I can get the value of ns2:count? <availableSlots xmlns:ns5="http://jabber.org/protocol/httpbind" xmlns:ns2="http://bindings.egain.com/chat" xmlns:ns4="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-stanzas" xmlns:ns3="jabber:client">
<ns2:count>1</ns2:count>
</availableSlots>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you may need to look at [`.parseXML`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML/) to parse the xml also here is a good SO answer to parse xml with namespaces [jQuery XML parsing with namespaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/853740/jquery-xml-parsing-with-namespaces)

here is a good link too  [**Namespace Selectors for jQuery**](http://www.rfk.id.au/blog/entry/xmlns-selectors-jquery/)

**solution**

```
    xmlDoc = $.parseXML(xml),
    $xml = $(xmlDoc),
    $name = $xml.find( "ns2\\:name" ).attr("surName");

   alert($name);
```

here id the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Jbnev/

Comment: @Vicky you must post a new question containing the necessary information

Comment: @3nigma, just that jsfiddle link returns undefined. It needs to be used as a reference for future, edit that or try to remove that fiddle link.

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to add the namespace in your query for the name.

So you need something like:

```
/*[local-name()='list' and namespace-uri()='urn:foo1:foo']
```

Comment: what do you mean? instead of ns2:...?

Comment: Edited...maybe also googling for xpath and namespaces might help you out even more.

Answer (score 1):

Doesnt /list/employees/user[@id='test']/name/@firstName work?