# What is the correct jquery 1.7.1 find syntax for parsing xml with namespaces?

Tags: jquery, xml-namespaces

I'm using jQuery 1.7.1 and IE8 to parse some XML namespace data from a SharePoint list.  I have tried all of the "find" syntaxes in [jQuery XML parsing with namespaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/853740/jquery-xml-parsing-with-namespaces/12074483#12074483), but none are working for me. What's the "find" syntax that works for jQuery 1.7.1 with IE8?

Comment: I should have been more precise.  I'm using URL Protocol from a remote  client to access a calendar list on SP 2003 (I know it's OLD, but I have no control over that!).  So I'm not using jQuery inside SP.

Answer (score 0):

You'll find more details about the issue and a workaround in this blog post:
http://sympmarc.com/2011/11/08/problem-with-jquery-1-7-and-spservices/

Now, my two cents: don't use jQuery for namespaced xml, just use regular JavaScript. I have done this in SharePoint for years without any issue. You can find several examples (image rotator, pie/bar chart) here:
http://usermanagedsolutions.com/SharePoint-User-Toolkit/default.aspx

Comment: Tried all the jQuery approaches and pure JavaScript approaches using getElementsByTagName and getElementsByTagNameNS, but I couldn't get any of them to work with namespaces (worked great without namespaces).  I eventually returned the HTTP response as text and used JavaScript to search for the z:row rows and attributes.  Not so  elegant, but it worked.

Comment: @DanFerry the two references I posted in my reply are meant to work with SharePoint namespaces and are used by hundreds of sites. And both offer ways to contact the author if you're having issues.