# Parsing xml with special character

Tags: jquery, html, xml

I have the following xml with special character ":" in the object header. How to parse it.

```
<p606:ResponseData xmlns:p353="">
<p353:PersonId idOwner="loA">
<p353:IdValue name="78N">1fgsth</p353:IdValue> 
</p353:PersonId>
<p353:CInfo effectiveDate="2010-03-13" xsi:type="p353:cnt">
<p353:TCode>OYYT</p353:TCode> 
<p353:Ext>100</p353:Ext> 
</p353:ContactInfo>
</p606:ResponseData>
```

I used the following

```
xmlDoc = $.parseXML( xml ),
$xml = $( xmlDoc ),
$title = $xml.find( "p353:TCode" );
$( "#somePlace" ).append( $title.text() );
```

But it didn't work...moreover i want the value of effectiveDate from the follwoing line

```
<p353:CInfo effectiveDate="2010-03-13" xsi:type="p353:cnt">
```

How to do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you should escape the : character, it means pseudo class by default, in jQuery selectors.

```
$xml = $(xml);
Try this for title: $xml.find("p353\\:TCode").text();
And for date: $xml.find("p353\\:CInfo").attr('effectiveDate');
```

And the following question may helps you:
[jQuery XML parsing with namespaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/853740/jquery-xml-parsing-with-namespaces)

Comment: none of them are working            console.log($("p353\\:Ext").text());    console.log($(xml).find('[nodeName="p353:Ext"]'));

Comment: Oh man .. You are right... $ should be $xml.find in my example, i fixed it.
And $xml = $(xml);

Answer (score 1):

Those are prefixes which refer to namespace URIs. You need a naespace-aware parser. Please note that the name of the node is `ResponseData` not `p606:ResponseData`.

The prefixes should be declared somewhere in the parent chain of the element like:

```
<p606:foo xmlns:p606="http://www.example.com/portal/606">
    <p606:bar property="value"/>
</p606:foo>
```

In the fragment it is clear that `p353` is not defined.