# Jquery to iterate through a list

Tags: javascript, jquery

Following jQuery is not working on given select box.

I want to iterate through all the options of select box.

Where am I going wrong?

Am not getting `alert("hi")`, I.E. `$("#FileType").find('x:option').each(function(){` is not executing.

```
<x:select id="FileType" width="210px">
        <x:option value="JPG">JPG</x:option>
        <x:option value="PNG">PNG</x:option>
        <x:option value="PDF">PDF</x:option>
        <x:option value="TIF">TIF</x:option>
        <x:option value="BMP">BMP</x:option>
</x:select>

$("#FileType").find('x:option').each(function(){
    alert("hi");                                
    if($(this).val() == AttachmentExtension)
    $("#FileType").val(AttachmentExtension);
});
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/853740/jquery-xml-parsing-with-namespaces for using xml namespaces with jquery

Answer (score 2):

You need to escape the `:` character in the selector.

```
$("#FileType").find('x\\:option').each(function(){
// Your logic. 
});
```

Here is jsFiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/bVz6F/

Answer (score 1):

I am not really sure what technology namespaces your `select`/`option` tags but the end result `HTML` does not have the namespaces. Change to:

```
$("#FileType").find('option').each(function(){
    alert("hi");                                
    if($(this).val() == AttachmentExtension)
    $("#FileType").val(AttachmentExtension);
});
```

Comment: @Romi Can you post the produced HTML after inspecting it.

Comment: <select id="FileType" width="210px">
<option id="t_3552" value="JPG">JPG</option>
<option id="t_3554" value="PNG">PNG</option>
<option id="t_3556" value="PDF">PDF</option>
<option id="t_3558" value="TIF">TIF</option>
<option id="t_3560" value="BMP">BMP</option>
</select>

Comment: @Romi That means the selector works fine, maybe something in the logic inside has to be change. For example what is AttachmentExtension?

Comment: Forget attachmentExtension, first alert should come. but something is worng with $("#FileType").find('option').each(function(){ that is reason control is not coming to alert()