# How to find element in atom xml file jquery?

Tags: jquery

I have a xml file like this:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<entry xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices" xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
<title />
<updated>2008-09-18T23:46:19.3857256Z</updated>
<author>
  <name>Dino</name>
</author>
<id />
<content type="application/xml">
  <m:properties>
    <d:Message>Mountain View</d:Message>
    <d:Age m:type="Edm.Int32">23</d:Age>
    <d:AmountDue m:type="Edm.Double">200.23</d:AmountDue>
    <d:BinaryData m:type="Edm.Binary" m:null="true" />
    <d:CustomerCode m:type="Edm.Guid">c9da6455-213d-42c9-9a79-3e9149a57833</d:CustomerCode>
    <d:CustomerSince m:type="Edm.DateTime">2008-07-10T00:00:00</d:CustomerSince>
    <d:IsActive m:type="Edm.Boolean">true</d:IsActive>
    <d:NumOfOrders m:type="Edm.Int64">255</d:NumOfOrders>
    <d:PartitionKey>mypartitionkey</d:PartitionKey>
    <d:RowKey>myrowkey1</d:RowKey>
    <d:Timestamp m:type="Edm.DateTime">0001-01-01T00:00:00</d:Timestamp>
  </m:properties>
</content>
```

I want to get `d:Message` `element`'s `value` in **jQuery**, how can I do that?
here is my code:

```
   $(document).ready(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "Insert_Log.xml",
            dataType: "xml",
            success: parseXml
        });
    });
    function parseXml(xml) {

        $(xml).find("d:Message").each(function () {

            $("#output").append($(this).text());
        });
    }
</script>
```

But it does not work!
I can use javascript `getElementsByTag("d:Message"`) get the value but I don't know how to use **jQuery**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to escape the colon (:) with a double backslash (\) :

```
$(xml).find("d\\:Message")
```

For more information, see [jQuery XML parsing with namespaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/853740/jquery-xml-parsing-with-namespaces)