# Why do I get blanks instead of version and date?

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, xhtml

I have this XML file (part of) and I need to get version and modify date with jQuery.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<package xmlns="http://www.idpf.org/2007/opf"
     version="3.0"
     xml:lang="nl"
     unique-identifier="isbn-id"
     prefix="cc: http://creativecommons.org/ns# rendition: http://www.idpf.org/vocab/rendition/# ibooks: http://vocabulary.itunes.apple.com/rdf/ibooks/vocabulary-extensions-1.0/">
  <metadata xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/">
        <meta refines="#title" property="title-type">main</meta>
        <meta property="ibooks:version">1.0.440</meta>
        <meta property="dcterms:modified">2014-06-08T21:15:17Z</meta>
...
```

This is the javascript/jQuery function that reads the version and date from above XML file:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$.ajax({
type: "GET",
url: "package.opf",
dataType: "xml",
success: function(xml) {
    var opf = $.parseXML( xml );

    $("span#datum").html($(opf).find("meta[property='dcterms:modified']").text());
$("span#versie").html($(opf).find("meta[property='ibooks:version']").text());
  },
error: function(jqHXR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    console.log(jqHXR);
    console.log(textStatus);
    console.log(errorThrown);}     
});
});
```

which puts version and date in an existing XHTML file, part of which is this:

```
 <p style="margin: 2em;" class="noind">Versie: <span id="versie">1.0.497</span>
 <br />Datum: <span id="datum">2014-06-05T22:15:50Z</span>
```

However: I get blanks. Version and date are overwritten by blanks.
How is that possible?

yes it is, I found. But like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $.get ('package.opf', function(xml) {
      $("span#datum").html($(xml).find("meta[property='dcterms\\:modified']").text());
      $("span#versie").html($(xml).find("meta[property='ibooks\\:version']").text());
    });
 });
```

where the .opf file is in the same directory as the xhtml file that contains the javascript.
But I don't think this works for an EPUB3 book in iBooks, because there, I see no change.

Answer (score 0):

It's jQ's handling of XML nodes & attributes with colons in their name; you need to escape them as such:

```
$("span#datum").html($(opf).find("meta[property='dcterms\\:modified']").text());
$("span#versie").html($(opf).find("meta[property='ibooks\\:version']").text());
```

**EDIT**

Updated to add jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7cu7g/

Comment: With double backslash? Then I see in Firebug "dcterms\:modified". SO I do one backslash. however, with one or two, i still get blanks.

Comment: Yes, double backslash: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/853740/jquery-xml-parsing-with-namespaces. I use jQ for parsing namespaced XML a lot (thanks SharePoint!) and so I'm used to it by now, though it wasn't obvious to me at first either.

Comment: Still only blanks...grrrrr. Maybe it's got something to do with namespaces?

Comment: Try outputting .length - do you get a 0 or a 1? That would tell you if you're getting a match on your selector.

Comment: console.log($(opf).find("meta[property='dcterms\\:modified']").text().length);  gives me 0

Comment: Sorry, I meant .length instead of .text() - the length value will tell you how many matching objects jQ found based on the selector specified.

Comment: 0. No matches at all.

Comment: neither does console.log($(opf).length);

Comment: The latter may be an indication of the problem then

Comment: Yep. The package.opf does not get read at all, it seems. Well, tomorrow will bring light. First sleep on it. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Erik - I created a quick jsFiddle to demonstrate this working; see edited answer.

Comment: Seen it. Thanks. So, it appears that the file is not read at all. Somehow it cannot find it, or there is an error in  it. I keep fiddling...

Comment: See my update of the original post. The parsing is not necessary.