# jquery get xml attribute value, escaping with \\ not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml

Note: I posted [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25043307/jquery-unable-to-get-xml-attribute-value) about this recently, but it was marked as duplicate because I didn't specify what I had tried clearly enough. I'll try to explain what I did better this time around.

Here's part of the XML file I'm trying to parse:

```
<entry>
<id>http://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/7ff84d8009d9a0b</id>
<updated>2010-04-11T12:47:03.281Z</updated>
<category scheme='http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#kind' term='http://schemas.google.com/contact/2008#contact'/>
<title type='text'>Name</title>
<link rel='http://schemas.google.com/contacts/2008/rel#edit-photo' type='image/*' href='https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/photos/media/7ff84d8009d9a0b/1B2M2Y8AsgTpgAm7PhCfg'/>
<link rel='self' type='application/atom+xml' href='https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/full/7ff84d8009d9a0b'/>
<link rel='edit' type='application/atom+xml' href='https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/full/7ff84d8009d9a0b/127099002381000'/>
<gd:email rel='http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#other' address='email@email.com' primary='true'/>
</entry>
```

Here is my JavaScript code:

```
$("#importData").append("<ul>");
xmlDoc = $.parseXML(data);
$xml = $(xmlDoc);
$xml.find('entry').each(function () {
    var name = $(this).find("title").text();
    var email = $(this).find('[nodeName="gd:email"]').attr('address');
    $("#importData").append("<li>" + name + " - " + email + "</li>");
});
//$(this).text() + " - " + $xml.find("gd:email[address]").index(i)
$("#importData").append("</ul>");
```

Here is a jsfiddle that attempts (unsuccessfully) to parse the XML: http://jsfiddle.net/DVXB9/4/

Here is another jsfiddle that successfully parses the XML with `gd:email` replaced by `gdemail` (no colon): http://jsfiddle.net/DVXB9/5/

I have tried various ways to parse my XML with namespaces, including `[nodeName=gd:email]`, `[nodeName="gd:email"]`, and `gd\\:email` as all suggested by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/853740/jquery-xml-parsing-with-namespaces) StackOverflow question. **However, none of them have worked successfully.**

I don't know how I should approach this next. Other people with XML similar in structure to mine have claimed that the aforementioned methods work properly. However, the best I have gotten is an outputted value of "undefined". What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is updated [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DVXB9/6/)

Just to get your example working I had to add namespace declaration `<entry xmlns:gd='http://www.some-url.org'>` otherwise `$.parseXML` throw the exception... after that you can use `$('gd\\:email, email',$xml)` to get access to the email node.

Comment: How did you figure that out? Thanks, adding that fixed the problem.