# Parse xml with namespaces using JQuery and working for all browser ..

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, xml-parsing

I'm trying to parse an XML response from a service using JQuery 1.11

At the moment my code works but only in Chrome, not for IE or Firefox and I need it works for all "modern" browsers.

Here you are a sample of my XML

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<wfs:FeatureCollection
   xmlns:ms="http://mapserver.gis.umn.edu/mapserver"
   xmlns:wfs="http://www.opengis.net/wfs"
   xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml"
   xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/wfs http://schemas.opengis.net/wfs/1.0.0/WFS-basic.xsd 
                       http://mapserver.gis.umn.edu/mapserver http://wms.pcn.minambiente.it/ogc?map=/ms_ogc/wfs/Numeri_Civici_2012.map&amp;SERVICE=WFS&amp;VERSION=1.0.0&amp;REQUEST=DescribeFeatureType&amp;TYPENAME=IN.NUMERICIVICI.2012&amp;OUTPUTFORMAT=XMLSCHEMA">
      <gml:boundedBy>
        <gml:Box srsName="EPSG:4326">
            <gml:coordinates>7.700007,44.802147 7.749396,44.849996</gml:coordinates>
        </gml:Box>
      </gml:boundedBy>
    <gml:featureMember>
      <ms:IN.NUMERICIVICI.2012 fid="IN.NUMERICIVICI.2012.2728384">

        <gml:boundedBy>
            <gml:Box srsName="EPSG:4326">
                <gml:coordinates>7.735138,44.810267 7.735138,44.810267</gml:coordinates>
            </gml:Box>
        </gml:boundedBy>
        <ms:boundary>
        <gml:Point srsName="EPSG:4326">
          <gml:coordinates>7.735138,44.810267</gml:coordinates>

        </gml:Point>
        </ms:boundary>
        <ms:id>13800026457291</ms:id>
        <ms:nome>Borgata Tetti Sotto</ms:nome>
        <ms:civico>16</ms:civico>
        <ms:istat>01004041</ms:istat>
        <ms:cap>12030</ms:cap>

        <ms:comune>CARAMAGNA PIEMONTE</ms:comune>
        <ms:nome_ted> </ms:nome_ted>
        <ms:provincia>CUNEO</ms:provincia>
        <ms:regione>PIEMONTE</ms:regione>
      </ms:IN.NUMERICIVICI.2012>
    </gml:featureMember>
    <gml:featureMember>

      <ms:IN.NUMERICIVICI.2012 fid="IN.NUMERICIVICI.2012.2736621">
        <gml:boundedBy>
            <gml:Box srsName="EPSG:4326">
                <gml:coordinates>7.735397,44.812403 7.735397,44.812403</gml:coordinates>
            </gml:Box>
        </gml:boundedBy>
        <ms:boundary>
        <gml:Point srsName="EPSG:4326">

          <gml:coordinates>7.735397,44.812403</gml:coordinates>
        </gml:Point>
        </ms:boundary>
        <ms:id>13800026457290</ms:id>
        <ms:nome>Borgata Tetti Sotto</ms:nome>
        <ms:civico>25</ms:civico>
        <ms:istat>01004041</ms:istat>

        <ms:cap>12030</ms:cap>
        <ms:comune>CARAMAGNA PIEMONTE</ms:comune>
        <ms:nome_ted> </ms:nome_ted>
        <ms:provincia>CUNEO</ms:provincia>
        <ms:regione>PIEMONTE</ms:regione>
      </ms:IN.NUMERICIVICI.2012>

    </gml:featureMember>
```

Here you are my code

```
var xmlText = $('#featureData').text(),
$xmlData = $.parseXML(xmlText),
$features = $('featureMember', $xmlData),
extractedFeatures = [];

$features.each(function () {
var $this = $(this),
    feature = {},
    items = [
        'nome',
        'civico',
        'istat',
        'cap',
        'comune'
    ],
    item;

for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    item = items[i];
    feature[item] = $this.find(item).text();
}

extractedFeatures.push(feature);
});

$('#output').text(JSON.stringify(extractedFeatures));
```

and [here you are my jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LkM4y/) so you can try it

Any suggestion or workaround? Thank you very much in advance ...

Cesare

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to be careful with namespaces... if you work with XML that has some namespaces declaration you have to keep it in mind and build appropriate selectors.

For example:

```
$features = $('gml\\:featureMember, featureMember', $xmlData),
```

Please take a look on update [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pshenichnov/48h9hzdu/1/). Now it works in FF and IE as well.

Comment: I need for an addendum ... Which notation I've to use for extract values of coordinates in my original sample XML <gml:Point srsName="EPSG:4326">          <gml:coordinates>7.735138,44.810267</gml:coordinates>         </gml:Point>  Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

This didn't worked for me, but I've found a working solution here:

http://jamesmcdonald.id.au/it-tips/google-chrome-xml-namespaces
On above page we can find this:

```
$(xml).find('ns1\\:ld_det, ld_det');
```

Where 'ns1' is namespace such as gml, and 'ld_let' is node name.

And it works in Google Chrome too.

Answer (score 0):

In case if someone is facing issues parsing XML with namespaces in MS Edge browser, here is the workaround:

```
$.fn.filterNodeByPrefix = function(prefix) {
    return this.filter(function() {
        return this.prefix === prefix;
    });
};
```

We can use this function as:

```
$('gml\\:featureMember, featureMember', $xmlData).filterNodeByPrefix('gml');
```

Tried and tested in Chrome, FF, IE and MS Edge.