# How to parse this data from xml response in jquery

Tags: jquery, xml

**XML RESPONSE**

```
(...)
<wfs:InsertResult>
<ogc:FeatureId fid="CRM_PROCES.1677" xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc"/>
<ogc:FeatureId fid="CRM_PROCES.1690" xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc"/>
</wfs:InsertResult>
(...)
```

I want to get fid number (In this case 1677, 1690) in jquery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [$.parseXML( data )](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML/) to create an XML Document in javascript. Then you can use jQuery to fetch stuff, like:

```
var xmlDoc = $.parseXML("<XML> COMES HERE </XML>");
var $xml = $(xmlDoc); // We <3 documentations with examples :)
var els = $xml.find("[fid]");
els.each(
    function (i,e) {
        console.log($(e).attr("fid"));
    }
);
```

I also recommend this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25089647/357403

Or you could do it with the builtin [DOMParser](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Parsing_and_serializing_XML), in XML mode:

```
var oParser = new DOMParser();
var xmltext = "<wfs:InsertResult> \
<ogc:FeatureId fid='CRM_PROCES.1677' xmlns:ogc='http://www.opengis.net/ogc'/> \
<ogc:FeatureId fid='CRM_PROCES.1690' xmlns:ogc='http://www.opengis.net/ogc'/> \
</wfs:InsertResult>";
var oDOM = oParser.parseFromString(xmltext, "text/xml");
var xDOM = $(oDOM);
xDOM.find("[fid]").each(
    function (i,e) {
        console.log($(e).attr("fid"));
    }
);
```