# what's a cross-browser compatible method for searching xml docs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, firefox, domparser

I'm trying to search for a specific node in an xml document; unfortunately, i can't seem to find a reliable way to do this, correctly, in a crossbrowser fashion. Given this setup:

```
var test1 = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?><test:things>\"things\"</test:things>"
var parser=new DOMParser();
var test2 =parser.parseFromString(test1,"text/xml");
```

in firefox this seems to work properly:

```
> $(test2).find("test\\:things")
[<test:things>​…​</test:things>​]
```

in chrome this seems to work properly:

```
> $(test2).find("things")
[<test:things>​…​</test:things>​]
```

haven't tried farther than that - is there a cross-browser safe method for performing this search? i'd rather not have to write two searches each time i need this functionality

Comment: since you tagged jquery, have you seen http://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsexml/? use normal jquery selectors to find what you need.

Comment: der ok i read a little closer... see this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1901903/152640

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery XML parsing with namespaces](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/853740/jquery-xml-parsing-with-namespaces)

Comment: On my machine, Firefox 32 returns a `parsererror`: "prefix not bound to a namespace", because the XML snippet doesn't declare the `test:` namespace. @blueberryfields, how did you get the code above to parse?