# javascript format for grabbing xml

Tags: javascript

I am trying to grab an xml tag with a prefix that is undefined in the xml sample `<feedburner:origLink></feedburner:origLink>`
not sure how to grab the xml with prefix.

```
var items = xml.find("item");
    $.each(items, function (i, v) {
        entry = {
              mp3: $(v).find("feedburner:origLink").text()}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery XML parsing with namespaces](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/853740/jquery-xml-parsing-with-namespaces)

Comment: `$(v).find("feedburner\\:origLink").text()`

Comment: the sample xml in your question is invalid