# Browser compatibility issues with JavaScript and jQuery Selectors

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, internet-explorer, compatibility

I am trying to find elements inside an XML response from an AJAX call, but I'm finding that the tag names are a bit odd. These tags are causing problems with my selectors.

The XML element I'm looking for in particular is `<d:Department>`. Using jQuery in Chrome I can find this element with `$(xml).find('Department')`. jQuery can't find the element in IE.

Using JavaScript I can get the element in Chrome using `xml.getElementsByTagName('Department')`. In IE I have to use `xml.getElementsByTagName('d:Department')`.

Is there a way to get this element in both browsers using JavaScript or jQuery without the need to look for both tag names?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Jquery:**

What version of jQuery are you using?

Be aware of the current IE support:

- jQuery 1.x   Internet Explorer 6+
- jQuery 2.x   Internet Explorer 9+

Try including the namespace in the find method like so:

```
$(xml).find('d\\:Department');
```

This is explained in [jQuery XML parsing with namespaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/853740/jquery-xml-parsing-with-namespaces)

**Javascript:**

Try to use getElementsByTagNameNS() like so:

```
xml.getElementsByTagNameNS("d", "Department");
```

see: http://www.w3schools.com/xml/met_document_getelementsbytagnamens.asp

Hope this helps!

Comment: I was still having trouble with the same code working in Chrome and IE. This eventually got it to work the same way on both. `$(rawXml).find('d\\:Department, Department')`.