# JQuery not able to process soap response

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, soap

I wrote the below code to process the soap xml response using jquery, but, jQuery is unable to read the response. Is there any syntax error I made in the below code? I don't see any errors in the console. Is there anything wrong in the soap message format or the way I am reading it?

I am a bit new to this kind of implementation.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script class="jsbin" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js">       </script>
<script>

    var xml = '<soapenv:Envelope      xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:web="http://siebel.com/WebService">\
  <soapenv:Header/>\
  <soapenv:Body>\
  <web:UpdateWO_Input>\
     <web:Comments>?</web:Comments>\
     <web:WOStatus>?</web:WOStatus>\
     <web:WONum>?</web:WONum>\
  </web:UpdateWO_Input><soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:web="http://siebel.com/WebService">\
  <soapenv:Header/>\
  <soapenv:Body>\
    <web:UpdateWO_Input>\
        <web:Comments>?</web:Comments>\
        <web:WOStatus>?</web:WOStatus>\
        <web:WONum>?</web:WONum>\
    </web:UpdateWO_Input>\
   </soapenv:Body>\
   </soapenv:Envelope>\
   </soapenv:Body>\
  </soapenv:Envelope> '

  var myObj=new Array(); 
  var index = 0;
  $(document).ready(function(){
   $(xml)
    .find('UpdateWO_Input').find('Comments')
    .each(function(){
        myObj[index] = $(this).text();
      index +=1;
    });

   for(var i =0; i< myObj.length;i++){
       $('body').append(myObj[i]+"<br/>");
    }

  });

  </script>

  <meta charset=utf-8 />
  <title>JS Bin</title>
   <!--[if IE]>
     <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js">  </script>
   <![endif]-->
   <style>
         article, aside, figure, footer, header, hgroup, 
            menu, nav, section { display: block; }
   </style>
    </head>
     <body>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery XML parsing with namespaces](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/853740/jquery-xml-parsing-with-namespaces)

Comment: I found it partly useful. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the answer to my QUestion. Below change is required in the javascript code

```
    var myObj=new Array(); 
    var index = 0;
      $(document).ready(function(){
      $(xml)
    .find('web\\:UpdateWO_Input')
    .each(function(){
        myObj[index] = $(this).text();
      index +=1;
    });

     for(var i =0; i< myObj.length;i++){
        $('body').append(myObj[i]+"<br/>");
     }

    });
```