# jQuery selecting a selector with namespaced element

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, namespaces

How would I select the following in jQuery?

```
<ns:text value="my value" />
```

I have tried the snippets below, but to no avail. Is this possible?

```
var x= $('ns:text').attr('value'); 
return x;
```

```
var x= $('text').attr('value'); 
return x;
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You're looking for:

```
var x= $('ns\\:text').attr('value'); 
return x;
```

Ref:

- http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors#Special_characters_in_selectors

Comment: what is the difference between two escapes and three escapes?

Comment: with 3 escapes, jquery will look for ns\:text  instead of ns:text

Comment: both work... so i would of thought they both are correct right?

Comment: It happens that 3 slashes works, because `\:` has no special meaning. By contrast, `'\\n'` would be a 2-char string, while `'\\\n'` would be the newline char

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at [JQuery, XML and namespaces](http://thompson-web.blogspot.com/2009/03/jquery-xml-and-namespaces.html).

It seems that this *should* work:

```
var x = $("ns\\:text").attr("value");
```

Comment: oops you posted it before while i was typing the answer but got my vote lol :)

Answer (score 2):

I tried the "[nodeName=gd:when]" version and it worked at first - but then when I upgraded jQuery from 1.4.3 to 1.5.2 it broke.  Not sure which version inbetween is the problem.

Solution was to use "gd\:when" approach - but it didn't work in Google Chrome - so I finally came up with a way that works in all the browsers I tried:

```
// Need to work out how to handle namespaces on some elements.
var namespace = "gd\\:"; // Most prefer this...
var startDateElement = $(this).find( namespace + "when" );
if( startDateElement.length == 0 )
{
    namespace = ""; // ...but some don't!
    startDateElement = $(this).find( namespace + "when" );
}
```

You can then use the prefix for any more namespaced elements.

See http://www.kajabity.com/index.php/2011/05/handling-xml-elements-with-namespaces-in-jquery/.

Answer (score 1):

Use a backslash, which itself should be escaped so JavaScript doesn't eat it:

```
   alert($('ns\\:text').attr('value') );
```

(as found on [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/128580/jquery-find-problem))

Answer (score 0):

```
$('ns\\\:text').attr('value')
```

seems to be the answer but some people have mentioned some browsers may not support it... but i don't know about that as this is a jquery library unless jquery has not implemented it then maybe that could be the case:

supported and tested on: ie8, FF 3.6, chrome 3.0
i have not tested it on other browsers because i don't have them but if anyone has the answer if it works on other browsers then please add on the comment below...

Answer (score 0):

### Works in webkit and alle the other Browsers too

> $('[nodeName=ns:text]').attr('value');

Example:

```
$('[nodeName=geo:lat]').attr('value');
$('[nodeName=geo:lat]').val();
```