# Select SVG element by inkskape:label attribute

Tags: jquery, svg, attributes, label

I have an external SVG loaded with the SVG Jquery plugin http://keith-wood.name/svg.html.
One line of the SVG is:
    `<g groupmode="layer" id="layer1" inkscape:label="myLabel"></g>`
I'm able to get the value of the label of that element by this line
    `$('#layer1', svg.root()).attr("inkscape:label");`
this will return the value "myLabel".
How do I select the same element using that value?
Tryed with
    `var myElement = $('g[inkscape:label="myLabel"]', svg.root());`
with no luck.

Any suggestion?
TIA!

Answer (score 2):

according to [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2047466/jquery-selecting-a-selector-with-namespaced-element) referencing the [jquery docs](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/?rdfrom=http%3A%2F%2Fdocs.jquery.com%2Fmw%2Findex.php%3Ftitle%3DSelectors%26redirect%3Dno#Special_characters_in_selectors), your best bet would be `var myElement = $('g[inkscape\\:label="myLabel"]', svg.root());`.

Comment: have you tried iterating over the attributes of the `#layer1` element checking whether the `inkscape:label` attribute shows up at all and if it does under which name ?

Comment: tryed iteration with: 
             
    var attrs = $("#myElement")[0].attributes;
      for(var i=0;i<attrs.length;i++) {
      myLog(attrs[i].nodeName + " => " + attrs[i].nodeValue);
    }

and the result is correctly:

    inkscape:groupmode => layer
    id => myElement
    inkscape:label => myLabel
    style => display:inline
    transform => translate(-292.15131,615.25519)

but still can't select it by label value

Comment: you are inspecting attributes on the dom level. have a look at the accepted answer of [this so post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2224933/iterating-over-element-attributes-with-jquery) to see how to iterate over all attributes as jquery knows them. this should reveal how to address the namespaced ones.

Comment: @collapstar: thank you! but everything works if, inside the svg, i change "inkscape:label" to "label"; this way i can read label and select items by label

Answer (score 0):

It's been impossible for me to make it work as you request. The solution I have arrived, is duplicating the tag, but using an underscode instead of two dots, like this:

```
$('path').each(function() {
    $(this).attr({
        "inkscape_label" : $(this).attr('inkscape:label')
    });
});
```

Then I can select by the label I want like this:

```
$('[inkscape_label = ...
```

Answer (score 0):

For me the only solution that worked was [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59381801/2132157):

```
const t = document.querySelectorAll('g') 
const layer = Array.from(t)
    .filter(t => t.getAttribute('inkscape:label') === 'myLabel')[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

The title isn't very descriptive so I ended up here when trying to figure out how to select it via CSS.

In case it helps anyone else:

```
<style>
[inkscape\:label="MyNamedLayer"] {
   /*green*/
        filter: invert(42%) sepia(93%) saturate(1352%) hue-rotate(87deg) brightness(119%) contrast(119%);
        filter: invert(48%) sepia(79%) saturate(2476%) hue-rotate(86deg) brightness(118%) contrast(119%);
    }
</style>
```