# Select a node with namespace in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, namespaces

I'm using YQL to fetch data using JSONP, and it returns a string of XML. I parse it using `$.parseXML` and put it inside the jQuery selector and try to select a node. However, it contains a namespace (for example, `yweather:`) and jQuery seems to not working as it should be.

From [other SO answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2047466/jquery-selecting-a-selector-with-namespaced-element) they suggested that doing `\\:` will solve it. It does, but only when the data I received is XML (mine is with JSONP.)

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql",
    data: {
        q: "select item from weather.forecast where location=48907",
        format: "jsonp"
    },
    dataType: "jsonp"
}).success(function(data){
    var xml = $.parseXML(data.results[0]);
    console.log($("yweather\\:condition", xml));
});
```

It didn't match anything.

Comment: can get data from same table in YQL as json results instead of xml...personally that's easier to work with IMO. Go to [YQL console](http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/console/#h=select+*+from+weather.forecast+where+location%3D48907) and select `json` format  and note the json format added to url generated in console

Comment: demo for same location in michigan , data all in json http://jsfiddle.net/faNaM/

Comment: @charlietfl - I just noticed YQL allows cross origin requests, thanks.

Comment: figured you would notice that by me using `get`. Yes is very under used service, but can be really handy in app with no server support. Have even used it to scrape html using their xpath selectors

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 Please have a look at my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could not figure out why it is not working, also other answers suggested escaping `:` with `\\`. But it is not working. So I have tried in this way and it is working. This is also equal to jQuery's `find` method and it is working [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/raEdB/13/)

Code is

```
  var xml = $.parseXML(data.results[0]);
  xml = $(xml).find('channel item');
  var weatherList = xml.find('*').filter(function(){
     return this.tagName === "yweather:condition";
  });
  console.log(weatherList);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 There is no difference between `$('yweather:condition', xml)` in your code and `$(xml).find('*').filter(function(){..})` . Both does the same number of iterations. I assume this is matching your criteria.

Comment: To be fair it did solve the problem. Thanks! However, the reason why jQuery can't select it remains unknown.