# jQuery > 3.0.0 selecting a namespaced element

Tags: jquery, xpath, jquery-selectors

How do you select element with namespace with jQuery > 3.0.0 ?

It looks like [jQuery selecting a selector with namespaced element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2047466/jquery-selecting-a-selector-with-namespaced-element) doesn't work anymore. (Or I don't use it correctly)

```
<feed xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices" xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata" xmlns:georss="http://www.georss.org/georss" xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml" xml:base="https://portal.foo.fr/sites/foo/_api/">    
  <entry>
    <content type="application/xml">
      <m:properties>
        <d:Title>titre</d:Title>
```

- $("Title") => OK 1 item
- $("d\\:Title") => KO 0 item
- $("d\\\:Title") => KO 0 item
- $("properties Title") => KO 0 item
- $("content Title") => OK 1 item
- $("content properties Title") => KO 0 item

It looks like protection with \ doesn't work at all.
OK I'll be more than happy if I can ignore the namespace.
But this doesn't work either.
"grandfather child" works. But not "father child" or "grandfather father child"

https://jsfiddle.net/qhgobLen/2/

Comment: hmm... isn't your \ on the wrong side?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/00fyL0bd/1/

Comment: as an aside, the question you linked to was posted in january 2010, the user was likely using jquery 1.3.2. That was a loooong time ago in the programming world. it has gone through quite a few changes between now and then, so undoubtably things have changed, both in jQuery and the browser's dom api.

Comment: @Kevin B. Yes it was. But even with the backslash on the right (or rather left) side it still doesn't work . Thank you for your fiddle. I created mine frome yours.