# how to replace these tag pasted into htmleditor from word

Tags: jquery, html, regex, ms-word

I pasted some content from word to htmleditor()【http://mindmup.github.io/bootstrap-wysiwyg/】，but some word-defined tags still in html like "< v:shape>< /v:shape>" and  "< v:shapetype>< /v:shapetype>" and  "< v:imagedata>< /v:imagedata>" and so on...

I have removed most of useless tag with jquery except this kind of tags .

all the followings dont work, like `$(xxxxxx).find('v')/.find('v:shape')/.find('shape');`. but `$(xxxxxx).find('a')/.find('span')` works well.

i want to use Regular Expressions to replace all `< v:xxx>< /v:xxx>` tags to `< vword>< /vword>` then remove all vword tags, but i dont know Regular Expressions syntax and in these 2 days i have no time learn it and i wonder whether it's the right way.

so,who can kindly tell me how and what i should do? thx.

this works well:

```
container.find("font").each(function () {
$(this).replaceWith(function () { return $(this).contents(); });
});
```

this doesnt work:

```
container.find("v").each(function () {
$(this).remove();
});
container.find("shape").each(function () {
$(this).remove();
});
container.find("shapetype").each(function () {
$(this).remove();
});
container.find("v:shape").each(function () {
$(this).remove();
});
container.find("v:shapetype").each(function () {
$(this).remove();
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I　used other ways to fix the problem:

First,

```
    container.find('*').each(function () {
        if ($(this).get(0).tagName == 'V:SHAPE') {
            $(this).remove();
        }
    });
```

Second, 
i found another post about this kind of tag: http://forum.jquery.com/topic/jquery-colon-in-xml-tag-on-webkit-cannot-select
but it doesnt work for me.
i searched 'jquery select tagname with colon' by google, and got this: [Parsing XML with namespaces using jQuery $().find](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/128580/jquery-find-problem)
then i changed my solution to :

```
container.find('v\\:shape').each(function () {
    $(this).remove();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Is there supposed to be a space after each "<"? Assuming that's a typo, this should work for you:

match: `<v:(\w+)>(.*?)</v:\1>`

replace: `<v\1>\2</v\1>`